# Optimising the new users experience VS. Community (My question on hold)

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Yesterday I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403104/what-programming-language-is-used-in-google-search) about the programming language used in a product. Today, however, I see that the question was put on-hold.

Before asking the question, I made sure to focus on what I am curious to know/confirm. As we are talking about a search engine, I specifically mentioned that I wanted to know about the back-end part. And I was inspired by questions previously answered:

[What Language is Used To Develop Using Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989689/what-language-is-used-to-develop-using-unity)

[What programming language is used in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458979/what-programming-language-is-used-in-google-sheets)

Assuming that the rules of the site have not changed in relation to the questions I have researched before; The first and only comment that my question has justifies the presence of my question on the site, since it did not indicate to me an alternative site to carry out the question.

Many times negative votes take place as a butterfly effect, and veteran users actually end up not wanting to help and belittle an issue that is not carried out by someone else, that's just my opinion, but I think there are new users that basically come to this site and never come back.

I also see 'exemplary' users making comments that do not address the issue itself.

However, I do not expect my question to be answered or voted in favour, because I am used to these situations. However despite continuing to use the site because it has immense quality, it seems that somehow new registered users are driven out to other sites because of some community members.

I have nothing against this system, but I think the company could optimise the experience of new users a little more.

Edit:

I deleted the original post because I somehow believed my post was of poor quality. Stackoverflow's own page recommended the following questions::

[What language was Google written in at the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882180/what-language-was-google-written-in-at-the-beginning)
[What database does Google use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362956/what-database-does-google-us)
...

The result of page 404 presented links that I had not found before using the site search. And they are also similar to the question I made and I believe that if they were that bad they would not have visibility on this same page.

I accept that if the site generally accepts these questions, there may be abuses. And the community's attitude to these potential abuses is normal. I can also assume that questions on the site do not escape the rules because there are no warnings there. And in that respect, yes, there is something wrong with the way the community treats these new users, who have done nothing wrong, because those questions are there, and from the moment they are treated differently. And it's not the community's fault at all.

However, the links on 404 page (my deleted question) satisfied me greatly!

Comment: It's important to note in cases like this that the existence of an older, similar, question not closed isn't necessarily evidence that said older similar question is actually on topic. There are rather important differences in this case between your question and the two you referenced.

Comment: ...This is why things like historical locks and keeping content of this flavor on the site is a poor idea.  We get people who are misled by it and believe that this kind of posting is a good idea.

Comment: So there is room for the company to improve, and make sure that new users of the site are not simply potentially run off to another site.

Comment: @ANormalUser: That we no longer allow these sorts of questions *is an improvement.*

Comment: @Makoto I do not say finish the old posts, but put a warning on these questions to say that they do not follow current rules or standards.

Comment: @yivi My question is related to the programming language used by programmers. The other questions only differ in the fact that it is the language used by customers.

Comment: This feels like an informational type of question instead of a "I have a problem that I need the answer to" type of question. The former is best asked on quora, the latter is best asked here.[Edit]:  After visiting the question and seeing someone post a link to quora I can't say I'm surprised.

Comment: If you're genuinely concerned about all of this, you could do the company and community a great service by telling us how we can better educate new users on how the site works, so that they can avoid these pickles.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not, people like me need as little distractions as possible, and this is a good thing about that. I just wanted you to suggest me which site to go to in these type of questions in this case, Quora .

Comment: I really must disagree with the argument made in this question that new users are discounted by the company. One need only search Meta Stack Overflow for [the `welcoming` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming) to find just how far the company is willing to go to be welcoming to new users.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: @HereticMonkey **potentially affected, not that they're actually affected. I was referring to users who search for questions similar to yours and end up being classified negatively. And not all new users. Still I accept my question is poor. But still.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Excuse my lack of ability to express myself . On the one hand, I understand that the community is doing the right thing, as I said in my edit. I never meant it's the community's fault, because it's not.

Answer (score 14):

In this case though, the problem is not that "these questions were on-topic before but no longer". Your question is fundamentally different from the ones you are using as a comparison.

Those two questions that you link, good or bad, are about what programming language you have to use to work with certain specific tools. Well, the second one may not be even that, but at least one answerer interpreted it that way.

The question you asked is a trivia question: *"What language did Google use to build their product"*. It's not a *"practical, answerable programming question"*.

The questions are not comparable, and your got to the wrong conclusions about topicality in your research.

Comment: I suspect the language used was C++, I just wanted to confirm that assumption. The difference which you call "fundamentally different" is that I wanted to know the language used on the server side and not on the client side, but I hadn't noticed that detail.

Comment: Whether it's server side or client-side doesn't matter all that much.  If someone asked the question "what language does Git use," we'd have the same response.

Comment: @ANormalUser No, the question that asks about "what language is used in the frontend" is also a very poor question. It's only saving grace is that some user interpreted generally as "how do I use formulas on Google Sheets".

Comment: @yivi In that case, a new user can feel treated in kinda biased way, so that's the reason of my post. Like "If olders posts are right why my is wrong?"

Comment: @Anormal Posts are not evaluated by an algorithm, but by other community members. There is an element of luck in crowd-based systems. The user that asked that poor question "got lucky", because their question didn't attract enough attention. Otherwise it would have been downvoted and close-voted. Now that it's getting more attention, I doubt it'll stay that way.

Comment: @yivi Despite not participating actively I think the community is important, and I don't agree Stackoverflow shouldn't pursue that, but I think what manners is the question itself. If the question is valid, the question shouldn't have negative votes in a timespan, or others rules. Or the site should know what the factors of "got lucky" questions, to manage the others, or something . The question is the one which attract external visitors. The rest should be evaluated only by the community. The question being managed like 1% Stackoverflow 99% community, should be enough, and the search as well.

Answer (score 10):

[This question in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989689/what-language-is-used-to-develop-using-unity) is not asking what language Unity is written *in*, but rather what languages you can use to write *using* this SDK.  This is *valuable* for developers who want to actually write Unity but are intimidated by the barrier to entry.

**Not** the same as your question.

[Your second example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458979/what-programming-language-is-used-in-google-sheets) isn't a good question at all, honestly - a net-zero score asking about this probably should've been closed by now.  It's a miracle in and of itself that it missed that chance.

Why is it off-topic?  The definition of "language" is ambiguous.  The answer on that question gives one using "spreadsheet formulas" as a language, and at best that's a DSL since you can mostly use formulas like this across Excel clones.

To your question, it is off topic simply because **we do not work with the Google stack**.  Additionally, an answer to this question fundamentally matters little in the grand scheme of things; unless you were hired on to work with Google Search directly, you wouldn't benefit from having that knowledge.